# Codility task TapEquilibrium correctness only 33%

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I attempted the Codility task 'TaskEquilibrium' and received only 33% under the Corectness criterion. You can review my C++ code along with the problem statement in the following link:

https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingAPHQW7-UVM/

My approach in the problem is to initially calculate the sum of the elements of the array. Then I find the difference in each iteration (differently for the first iteration) and update the minimum absolute value.

I was able to check for the mentioned test case but did not receive correct answers to some other cases.

Please review my code and advise where is the algorithm faulting. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

One big flaw in your logic is, you assume `P` is at least 1, but there are cases that `P = 0` is giving you the minimum difference.

e.g. for list of `[1,-1]`, you want `P=0` so that it gives you `[]` and `[1,-1]` which gives you the minimum difference `0`

another problem is, when you loop through each element, you have not updated your `diff` (`diff` is always `sum of A[1..N] - A[0]`), hence the `temp = diff + 2*A[p-1];` is not going to give you meaningful result when `p > 2`.

Your loop should look like (pesudo-code):

```
minDiff = sum;
diff = sum;
for each (int a in A) {
    diff -= (a * 2);
    if (abs(diff) < minDiff) {
        minDiff = abs(diff);
    }
}
```

It is a good idea to keep only diff like this but if it confused you, why don't you simply keep two var, e.g. `sumOfFirstSection = 0; sumOfSecondSection = sum`, and have a loop for each element in `A[]`, and do `sumOfFirstSection += A[i]; sumOfSecondSection -= A[i]` and derive the difference accordingly?

Comment: Maybe because there isn't an on-topic question to answer. If you really want to answer this, you could also spend some time making the question on-topic, for example by posting an MCVE, and specifying a clear question.

Comment: well, then I believe it is the question to receive the downvote, not the answer, isn't it?